# как поменять переменную в событии ангуляр 2

Tags: angular2

Есть форма, если пользователь ввел какой-то текст в поля и пытается его закрыть мы должны его спросить, уверен ли он что хочет закрыть форму с изменнеными данными которые потеряются.
Есть экшн:

```
this.addHandler(actions.ChangeQrCodeValueAction,
  (action) => {
    const originQRCodeInfoVO = action.payload.qrCodeInfoVO;
    if (action.payload.value) {
      const tempInfoMap = 
        action.payload.qrCodeInfoVO.info.map((tempQrCodeInfoVO) => {
        if (tempQrCodeInfoVO && 
        action.payload.value.hasOwnProperty(tempQrCodeInfoVO.name) &&
          tempQrCodeInfoVO.qrCodeType === 
        action.payload.qrCodeTypeIdentifier) {
          tempQrCodeInfoVO.value = 
        action.payload.value[tempQrCodeInfoVO.name];
          return tempQrCodeInfoVO;
        } else {
          return tempQrCodeInfoVO;
        }
      });
      originQRCodeInfoVO.info = tempInfoMap;
      return {qrCodeInfoVO: originQRCodeInfoVO, isChanged: true};
    }
  });
```

так вот он возвращает isChanged = true если что-то меняется в форме (по дефолту isChanged = false) Все отрабатывает хорошо, кроме одного момента, когда я что-то ввел в форме и нажал cancel(т.е. остался в форме) после чего я закрыл её и нажал да - хочу закрыть и потерять изменения, в следующий раз когда я открываю форму и не вношу изменений, меня спрашивает хочу ли я закрыть итд. Я выяснил что это происходит из-за того что 1 раз сетается isChanged и обратно она уже false не становится. Мне нужно в функции закрытия формы onDestroy() каким-то образом сетать переменную isChanged в false каждый раз, что бы всё работало. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можете скинуть немного больше кода, не понятно по тому куску кода что вы отправили.

Comment: @Zicrael а что именно вам скинуть?)

Comment: Скиньте как вы вызываете свой код, как инициализируете и т.д